# ASP.NET core 5 web api connect exchange via powershell script

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, exchangewebservices

In my asp.net core 5 project I want to execute the ps script below. This script can be executed in a native powershell without errors. And I can run simple ps scripts in my project context. But if I run this script via IIS Express (same machine as native powershell) then it thrwos the following error msg:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null.
> Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
> command again.

The msg belongs to the `Import-PSSession` command. How to run the script in asp.net core project context?

```
$Username = 'user'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

$ExchangeFQDN = 'exchange.domain'
$ConnectionURI = "http://$($ExchangeFQDN)/powershell"
try{
    $mSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $ConnectionURI -Credential $Cred -Authentication Kerberos
    Import-PSSession $mSession -DisableNameChecking
}catch{
    echo $_
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After translating the script to c# commands as you can see below (the code snippet was adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575651/powershell-generic-session-and-import-this-session-in-exchange-remote-management)) I gpt the following error msg:

> System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException
> HResult=0x80131501   Message = An error has occurred which PowerShell
> cannot handle. A remote session might have ended. ... Inner Exception
> 1: NotSupportedException: BinaryFormatter serialization and
> deserialization are disabled within this application. See
> https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.

And I found a solution for it [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14032).

```
<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
```

Just add the line above to your project file into section `<PropertyGroup>`.

```
        string username = @"domain\username";
        string password = "password";
        SecureString ssPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char x in password)
            ssPassword.AppendChar(x);
        PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(username, ssPassword);
        var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(@"http://servername/powershell"), @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credentials);
        connInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        connInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
        connInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

        var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo);
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline plPileLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command smGetMailboxForward = new Command("get-mailbox");
        smGetMailboxForward.Parameters.Add("Identity", "john.doe");
        plPileLine.Commands.Add(smGetMailboxForward);
        Collection<PSObject> result = plPileLine.Invoke();
        plPileLine.Stop();
        runspace.Close();
        runspace.Dispose();
```